# Return type of a constructor in c++

Tags: c++, constructor, return, return-type

I am learning c++, and I came across following code segment:

```
class X
{
    int i;

public:
    X(int ii = 0);

    void modify();
};

X::X(int ii)
{ i = ii; }

void X::modify()
{ i++; }

X f5()
{ return X(); }

const X f6()
{ return X(); }

void f7(X& x) // Pass by non-const reference
{ x.modify(); }

int main()
{
    f5() = X(1);
    f5().modify();
}
```

I am stuck particularly in this segment-

```
X f5()
{ return X(); }
```

Does this part of code return an object of type x by value? Can a constructor return an object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does this part of code returns an object of type x by value?

Yes, it creates and value-initialises a temporary object of type `X` (by calling the constructor with the default value of zero) and returns that.

> can a constructor can return an object?

No, that doesn't make any sense. But an conversion expression like `X()` does.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for Thanks!!. Just one more doubt, what does it mean by "value-constructs"? An object is instance of class, what is value of object. Value of inbuild type make sense like int i=15, but what can be possibly a value of user defined type object?

Comment: @theindividual: For a class like this, with a default constructor, value-initialisation calls the default constructor; so `i` will be zero. For other types it would initialise them to zero.

Answer (score 3):

`f5` is just function, not constructor. And it returns constructed object of type `X`.

Comment: Thanks. I know f5() is function. what about return x(). It seems like x() have a return type?. X is constructor here?

Comment: @theindividual return `X()` means construct temporary variable of type `X` and return copy of it.

Answer (score 1):

simple, you misunderstand the constructor of the class and a function. your class `class X` have a constructor and it is `X(int ii = 0);`.

`X f5()` is not a constructor. Clearly understand that first.

Constructor of a class should have the same name as class and have no a return value. It does,t make any sense. (read further about class and constructor)

```
X f5() {
  return X();
}
```

This is a function which returns a `X` type of object. it returns the X().

`X()` creates a value-initialized temporary object of type `X`.

Comment: Yes I know, f5 is not a constructor. x() is constructor.  two statement which i don't understand are return x(), what does it mean by x()? and second f5()=x(1)

Comment: @the individual : yes, I got it. X() creates a value-initialized temporary object of type X. It performs an initialization.