# Does C++ constructor return an object?

Tags: c++

All books and internet pages I read say that C++ constructors do not have a return value and they just initialize an object:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Number {
    int m_val{};

public:
    Number() = default;
    Number(int val) : m_val(val) {}

    int val() { return m_val; }
};

int main() {
    Number n;  // Initializing object with defualt constructor
    std::cout << n.val() << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

But it turns out that also I can use constructors for assignment and for calling methods of object, like it returns the value of this object:

```cpp
Number n = Number(10);                 // This works
std::cout << Number(29).val() << '\n'; // And this
```

In other similar stackoverflow questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29941885/return-type-of-a-constructor-in-c) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18161597/it-seems-at-a-glance-that-a-constructor-return-an-object) people write that this semantics creates a value-initialized temporary object of type `Number` , but it does not answer my question.

So does constructor return object, or maybe it is some c++ entity that i've never heard of?

Comment: `Number(10)` is not a call to the constructor, it's the creation of an object. Constructor definition and object creation just happen to follow similar syntax, i.e. using the class name in a "function-like" manner (this saves on reserved words, which C++ has always preferred) . Constructors themselves do not have names and can't be referred to in code.

Comment: "_Value-initialized_" has a specific technical meaning. It is a form of initialization that applies specifically only if there is _no_ argument in the parentheses. So it doesn't apply to your example, nor the second link.

Comment: It's not really worth to consider constructors in the same way as other functions. It's one of the *special member functions*, and it's special because it doesn't have a name, uses a specificly defined syntax and is called in specific situations. You technically can't call the constructor yourself, it is invoked when object is created.

Comment: @SoldatovAndrey Since you commented "Thank you" on the answers: Please have a look at [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: `Number n = Number(10);` is **not** assignment, despite the `=` sign; it's still initialization.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen [Here](https://godbolt.org/z/jdc5hGTP9) I call the constructor directly ;)

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili Evil genius but alas not portable. I was thinking if you could could bind `std::function` to a constructor and call it that way.

Comment: @Bathsheba That's flattering, especially coming from you! I doubt you can get it working with `std::function` since there is no way to take address of the constructor that I know of, other than the `extern "C"` trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed a constructor doesn't have a return value.

But `Number(10)` is an object of type `Number`. And *that* is an expression with a value.

Comment: Isn't it more accurate (at least since C++17) to call `Number(10)` a prvalue expression?  No temporary is created in `Number n = Number(10);`.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Indeed it is. I'll remove, and upvote the better answer for good feelings.

Answer (score 4):

> Does C++ constructor return an object?

No, a constructor doesn't return anything. A constructor will be called when an object is created and the implicit `this` will point to the object that is being constructed.

---

P.S.

> But it turns out that also I can use constructors for assignment and for calling methods of object, like it returns the value of this object:
>
> ```
> Number n = Number(10);
> ```

That's not an assignment. That syntax of copy-initialisation.

Comment: *That's not an assignment. That syntax of copy-initialisation.* `n = Number(10)` but this is an assignment, so rather missed point as for op's interest about the ctor call syntax.

Comment: @bloody That is an assignment, yes. The answer to OP's question is no. I don't see how that misses the point.

Comment: I assume op doesn't care about strict nomenclature but the ctor call syntax in assignments/initializations vs return value mechanism.

Comment: @bloody `I assume op doesn't care about strict nomenclature` If that's the case, then now is a good time to start caring. `but the ctor call syntax` There is no syntax to call a constructor in C++. There are various ways of creating objects, and the language always calls the constructor for you.

Comment: @eerorika: Placement new does, almost. I know what you mean though. You *can* call a destructor explicitly of course. I wonder if some `~~C()` notation could be used to call a constructor in future standards?

Comment: *There is no syntax to call a constructor in C++* . Everyone I know in the industry calls invoking a constructor() 'calling a constructor'. Otherwise there are no function calls either, language calls them for you.  Note that ppl often discuss visible code structure for clear reference among them and communication. In that context yes - there is a constructor call. First time I can hear this term is reserved for some language internal snobbery. And certainly such revelations don't help ppl solve their problems on SO.

Comment: @bloody Object creation does more than just calling the constructor. If the object is on the stack, it allocates memory of appropriate size and alignment, and then calls the constructor. If it's a member variable, simply passes in the already-allocated memory, etc. It's not helpful to anyone to lump all that magic into calling it a "function call". It's nice when words mean something.

Comment: *"There is no syntax to call a constructor in C++"* When you "call" a constructor of a base class (or an overloaded constructor of the same class) on the initialization list it is NOT an object creation (just part of that process) and a literal counter-example of your "oracle": a call but not an allocation. The rest about helpfulness and words meaning I won't even comment since what are they worth if they are simply wrong.